# Selecting the first 20 turtles out of 1000 turtles

Tags: netlogo

```
turtles-own [wages]

to setup
  clear-all
  setup-patches
  setup-turtles
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  move-turtles
  get-employed
  tick
end

to move-turtles
  ask turtles [
    right random 360
    forward 1
  ]
end

to get-employed
  ask turtles [
    if pcolor = blue [
      set color green
      set wages wages + 10
    ]
    ifelse show-wages?
      [ set label wages ]
      [ set label " " ]
  ]
end

to setup-patches
  ask patches [set pcolor pink ]
  patch 0 0 [ set pcolor blue ]
end

to setup-turtles
  create-turtles 80
  ask turtles [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor ]
  ask turtles [ set color red]
end
```

I want to add the code to select the first 20 percent of the 80 turtles who comes in contact with the patch having color blue.

Comment: The text of your question says "20 percent", but your title says "20 turtles". Which one is it? And can you try to be more precise with your question? It is not at all clear to me what you are asking exactly...

Answer (score 1):

In your question is not clear how you will use the first 20% of turtles who get the blue patch so i assume you just want to store them in order to use this information later.

I would add a `turtles-own` called `is-first-20-percent?` set to `false` for every turtle.

Then, at the end of the `go` procedure, before the `tick` i would execute the `check-20` procedure as following:

```
to check-20

  if count turtles with [color = green] = (count turtles * 20 / 100) [
    ask turtles with [color = green] [set is-first-20-percent? true]
  ]

end
```

In every moment you can retrieve the first 20% of turtles who reached the blu zone with the command:

```
ask turtles with [is-first-20-percent?] [ ... do something ... ]
```

This code is working because 20% of 80 is an integer number (16) but if you plan to modify the starting number of turtles i suggest to modify the `check-20` procedure as following:

```
to check-20

  if (count turtles with [color = green] >= (count turtles * 20 / 100) 
      and count turtles with [is-first-20-percent?] = 0) [

     ask turtles with [color = green] [set is-first-20-percent? true]
  ]

end
```